# Percorrer um array sem saber seus indices

Tags: javascript, node.js

Eu possuo o seguinte array:

```
var array = {
    x: "Primeiro Valor",
    y: "Segundo Valor",
    z: "Terceiro Valor"
};
```

Eu gostaria de acessar os valores, porém, desconheço os indices `x,y,z`, é possível extrair esses valores?

Comment: Você precisa do índice ou somente o valor é importante?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso é um *Objeto*, para ler suas propriedades faça:

```js
var array = {
    x: "Primeiro Valor",
    y: "Segundo Valor",
    z: "Terceiro Valor"
};

for (var prop in array) {
    console.log("propriedade: " + prop + " valor: " + array[prop])
}
```

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade o que você tem aí não é um *array*, mas sim um *objeto*.

Mas é possível iterar por suas propriedades, usando `Object.keys()`, que converte o *objeto* num *array*:

```js
Object.keys(seuObjeto).forEach(function(key,index) {
  console.log(seuObjeto[key]);
});
```

[Referência **Objects.keys()** - Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: Não é necessário usar o `hasOwnProperty`, na definição do `Object.keys` já é dito que isso será feito. Pode olhar a implementação dele, ele já faz isso para você.

Comment: É verdade, pela implementação da Mozilla esta checagem já está sendo feita. Repeti porque achei que poderia não estar sendo, por precaução. Vou editar a resposta. Obrigado!