# Como extrair os valores dos campos de um Objeto javascript(JSON)?

Tags: javascript, json

Tenho um objeto Javascript qualquer, ex:

```
var pessoa = {nome: 'Carlos', cpf: '123', rg: '456'};
```

Preciso listar os campos que esse Objeto tem e os valores correspondentes.

> Para listar os campos eu consegui da seguinte forma:

```
Object.keys(pessoa);

//Saída no Console..
 nome
 cpf
 rg
```

> Agora preciso de um jeito de listar somente os valores dos campos..

```
//a saída deve ser assim..
  Carlos
  123
  456
```

seria algo como Object.values(pessoa), mas não tem esse método...

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Acho que pode te ajudar. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127924/percorrer-um-array-sem-saber-seus-indices/127926#127926

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tens de usar um loop, se precisas de isso numa array podes fazer assim:

```
Object.keys(pessoa).map(function(prop){ return pessoa[prop];});
// que dá ["Carlos", "123", "456"]
```

Podes também usar um `for in`, mas será como o Object.keys, um iterador de chaves:

```
for (var prop in pessoa){
    console.log(prop, pessoa[prop]);
}
// que dá : 
// nome Carlos
// cpf 123
// rg 456
```

Curiosamente na [biblioteca do MooTools](http://mootools.net/core/docs/1.5.1/Types/Object#Object:Object-values) tê-mos esse método. [A implementação é assim](https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Types/Object.js#L68-L76):

```
values: function(object){
    var values = [];
    var keys = Object.keys(object);
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
        var k = keys[i];
        values.push(object[k]);
    }
    return values;
},
```

Comment: Legal @Sergio, era isso mesmo que eu precisava, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

**Você pode usar um laço e colocar tudo em um outro array:**

```js
var data = [{"nome":"Eduardo","cpf":"00.666.999-33"},
{"nome":"Paulo","cpf":"222.222.666-33"}];



var nomes = [];
for(i = 0; i< data.length; i++){    
    if(nomes.indexOf(data[i].nome) === -1){
        nomes.push(data[i].nome);        
    }        
}

for(i = 0; i< nomes.length; i++){    
    alert(nomes[i]);      
}
```