# Extrair arrays e objetos do JSON retornado com jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, web-service

Estou fazendo uma requisição em um Web Service usando jQuery desta forma:

```
var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();

jQuery.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "http://meusite.com/test",
     data: dados,
     success: function( data )
     {
         // quero exibir os dados que estão dentro de data
      }
});
```

O JSON de retorno é exatamente esse quando o *login* do usuário está ERRADO.

```
{
    "error": true,
    "message": "Login failed. Incorrect credentials"
}
```

Caso a autenticação esteja CORRETA, o resultado é esse:

```
{
    "error": false,
    "user": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "fullname": "Romero Brito",
            "email": "romerobrito@gmail.com",
            "created_at": "2017-01-20 01:03:48"
        }
    ]
}
```

Como faço para extrair *arrays* e objetos do JSON retornado com jQuery? Como eu faço para exibir a mensagem que está dentro de `message` e os através do `data`?

**EDIT**

A princípio pode ser listado os dado simplesmente em um `alert()` ou até mesmo somente no `console.log()`.

Comment: Onde queres mostrar esses dados? numa tabela? num alert?

Comment: Você quer obter a propriedade `user`?

Comment: @Sergio a princípio não teria um local específico, somente em `log` ou até mesmo num `alert()`.

Comment: @Marconi quero obter os elementos retornados do JSON de dentro do `data`. Não somente o `user`, porém outros objetos.

Comment: @AckLay Seria percorrer as propriedades sem saber o que vem? Mais ou menos isso? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127924/percorrer-um-array-sem-saber-seus-indices/127926#127926

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa noite,

se você especificar no objeto de opções enviado ao método `.ajax` a key `dataType`, você informa qual tipo de dado você está esperando do servidor. No seu caso, seria algo assim:

```
jQuery.ajax({
     /* ... */
     dataType: 'json',
     /*... */
})
```

**Contudo**, como padrão (*default*), o jQuery tenta adivinhar - *Intelligent Guess* -, o formato do dado recebido (xml, script, json...) a partir da resposta do servidor. Então este parâmetro acima só precisaria ser informado caso o jQuery não conseguisse entender que a resposta se trata de um JSON (normalmente ocorre por culpa de uma mensagem mal formatada pelo servidor), ou você quer se certificar que o resultado será sempre esse (neste caso, se o jQuery não conseguir fazer o parse, ele irá invocar o callback `error`).

Dito isto, então, a sua função-callback `success` será invocada com o primeiro parâmetro contendo o **dado formatado** (*parsed*) (no seu caso, um objeto JavaScript). E você pode manipulá-lo como se estivesse manipulando um **objeto JavaScript** normalmente. Algo assim:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    /* ... */ 
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR )
     {
         /* seu dado já deve estar no parâmetro data */
         console.log("Login com sucesso? ", !data.error);
         if (!data.error) {
            var user = data.user[0]; //seu user é um array, então pego o primeiro elemento dessa array, por exemplo
            console.log("Nome completo do usuário: ", user.fullname);
         }
     }
});
```

O código acima é apenas para fins de *debug*, pois irá escrever no console do navegador.

Não sei se foi esta sua dúvida (sobre como manipular o dado recebido).

Se você quiser exibir uma mensagem simples, pode chamar o método [`alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/alert). Isto irá mostrar uma caixa de diálogo com a mensagem (bem simples).

Ou, se você quiser inserir esta mensagem no corpo da página de alguma forma, ou fazer interações de elementos, isto envolve manipulações no DOM, e pode ser feito facilmente pelo `jQuery`. Um exemplo bem simples:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    /* ... */ 
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR )
    {
        var textMessage;
        if (data.error) {
            textMessage = "Ocorreu um erro ao relizar o login: " + data.message;
        } else {
            textMessage = "Login realizado com sucesso! Bem vindo, " + data.user[0].fullname + "!";
        }
        $("body").append( $("<p></p>", { text: textMessage }) );
    }
});
```

O exemplo acima apenas adiciona ao `<body>` um `<p>` (parágrafo) com uma mensagem.

Comment: Legal sua explicação, mas não funfou cara. Tentei mostrar a parte da mensagem, porém aparece que `data.message` está `undefined`

Comment: @AckLay corrigi o último exemplo. Estava com a lógica invertida.

Comment: @AckLay era ali que estava dando o erro? o primeiro exemplo funcionou como você esperava?

Comment: O data.message funcinou de boa, porém o data.user[0].fullname não funciona.

Comment: Você pode fazer um `console.log(data);` e inspecionar seu objeto. Pode postar aqui o resultado? você postou lá em cima que a chave `user` recebe uma array. Então essa seria a forma de acessar aquele objeto. `data.user[0]` obtém o primeiro item da array `data.user`

Comment: Você tinha razão cara, eu estava errando em outra coisa aqui. Abraços. Vlw.

Comment: De nada. Boa sorte aí no projeto. Abraços

Answer (score 1):

Usando *dataType* como *json* é possível obter o retorno nesse formato para iterar as chaves ou valores.

```js
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/luccascosta/library/master/js/ret.json",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data['message']);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### Para o retorno de usuário

```js
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/luccascosta/library/master/js/user.json",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.user[0].fullname); // user[0] é para acessar o index zero do array de user. Dessa forma é possível acessar qualquer propriedade do objeto dentro desse array
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

PS: No exemplo está método `get` somente para ilustrar o retorno.

Comment: Isso funcionam para o `message`. E para o caso de `user`, como tem que ser feito? Desculpe a ignorância.

Comment: Nenhuma ignorância. Editei a resposta @AckLay.