# Ler Json sem precisar "saber" as chaves JAVA

Tags: java, json, arraylist

O problema é que eu preciso informar as profissões e queria que fosse automático a leitura do json sem precisar informar `ocup[1] = "jornalista"`. Gostaria que fosse automático a leitura do json.

```
{
  "profissao": {
    "jornalista": [
      "escritor",
      "legal",
      "fotografo"
    ],
    "programador": [
      "focado",
      "exatas",
      "articulado"
    ],
    "maquinista": [
      "senai",
      "mecanico",
      "articulado"
    ]    
  }
}
```

*Meu codigo é este*

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

//System.out.println(jsonObject);
JSONObject locs = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("profissao");
String[] ocup = new String[4];
ocup[0] = "jornalista";
ocup[1] = "programador";
ocup[2] = "maquinista";


ArrayList respostas = new ArrayList();

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String v;
int cont = 0;
while(cont < ocup.length){
    JSONArray jorn = (JSONArray) locs.get(ocup[cont]);
    //System.out.println(jorn);

    int y= 0;
     while(y < jorn.size()){
            String name = jorn.get(y).toString();
            System.out.println("digite s ou n você é "+name);
            v = scan.nextLine();
            if(v.equals("s")) {
                respostas.add(name);
            }

            y++;
        }
     cont++;
}

System.out.println(respostas.size());
```

Comment: Acho que pode te ajudar: [Percorrer um array sem saber seus indices](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127924/percorrer-um-array-sem-saber-seus-indices/127926#127926)

Comment: Sua pergunta está meio confusa. Você quer deixar o usuário preencher qual a ocupação por você?

Comment: o usuario nao vai preencher nenhuma ocupação simplesmente quero ler o json sem especificar as chaves! o usuario não irá cadastrar nada

Comment: O `JSON` está no formato que você especificou e logo abaixo o usuário vai adicionar as propriedades? (escritor, legal... etc?)

Comment: Desculpa eu sou meio novo nesse mundo,

Comment: o problema é o seguinte

Comment: eu preciso ler o arquivo, percorrer este json automaticamente para ler ele apenas, nao quero cadastrar nada nele, so quero ler ele entende? o problema é que se eu for colocar mais uma profissão no meu arquivo json, eu tenho que ir e colocar no array ocup[], porem acho que deve ter uma forma mais forma com menos trabalho pra fazer isso

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1):

A classe `JSONObject` possui um método chamada `keySet` que lista as chaves de um objeto:

```
JSONObject profissoes = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("profissao");

chaves = profissoes.keySet();

for (String chave : chaves) {
  System.out.println(chave);
}
```

Comment: valeu meu parceiro! tentei mas sem resultados! Muito obrigado ele aparenta ter erro na linha

Comment: chaves = json.getJSONObject("profissao").keySet();

Comment: @rodrigogabriel consegue colocar os imports?

Comment: @rodrigogabriel alterei meu exemplo para utilizar a mesma biblioteca que você está utilizando. Verifique se funciona pra você.