# Como listar objetos em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variáveis

Estou usando uma variável `object exp`:

```
var obj = {
nome: "Marcos",
snome: "Bonado",
idade: "314",
email: "MB@gmail.com",
tellW: "0123456789"
};
```

Quero listar os nomes e conteúdo de cada objeto. Tem algum modo de eu fazer isso?

Comment: Podes explicar melhor o que queres dizer com _"listar os nomes e conteúdo"_?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Percorrer um array sem saber seus indices](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127924/percorrer-um-array-sem-saber-seus-indices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para não ter problema com incompatibilidade entre navegadores use o `for`

```js
var obj = {
nome: "Marcos",
snome: "Bonado",
idade: "314",
email: "MB@gmail.com",
tellW: "0123456789"
};

for (var k in obj){
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
         console.log("Chave: " + k + ", Valor: " + obj[k]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

```
function (data) {
    var keys = Object.keys(data);

    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro você deve criar um array e armazenar os objetos. Depois para listar no console os objetos do array vc pode usar o console.log(array). Se quiser ver o conteúdo de cada objeto de forma isolada vc pode fazer um laço for.

Por exemplo:

```
var objeto = {"nome":"Bruno"};
var objeto2 = {"nome": "teste"};

var array = [objeto, objeto2];
console.log(array);

for(var i=0; i < array.length; i++){
  console.log(array[i]);
}
```